# Deployment Rule Set Required Java version not available

Tags: java

Hi I am running windows 7 on a 32 bit machine and I recently upgraded to Java 1.7.0_51 and now I can't access certain java applets. I have tried to configure the Deployment Rule Set by following this tutorial

http://wraithhacker.com/java-deployment-rule-set/

and I pretty much got everything working as illustrated. However when I try to visit the application I get the error that Application Blocked by Deployment Rule Set. Deployment Rule Set required Java version 1.6.0_45 not available.

I Not also the Java Console does not show up at all.

The Java versions installed on my system from the is 1.6.0_29 and 1.6.0_22 I have tried both in my ruleset.xml file but they haven't worked.

```
`<ruleset version="1.0+">
  <rule>
    <id location="https://10.0.0.1" />
   <action permission="run" version="1.6.0_22" />
  </rule>
  <rule>
    <id location="http://www.customs.gov.dm/" />
    <action permission="run" version="1.6.0_22" />
  </rule>
  <rule>
    <id />
    <action permission="block">
      <message>Blocked by NTRC Management</message>
    </action>
  </rule>
</ruleset>`
```

c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_22\bin>java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Sites>java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

So I am sure that I have both versions of Java installed.

However if you go to java control panel and view the JNLP file I notice the following line

```
<java initial-heap-size="67108864" max-heap-size="268435456" java-vm-args="-XX:MaxNewSize=1024k" version="1.5+"/>
```

and for the other applet I notice the following

```
<java initial-heap-size="536870912" max-heap-size="1073741824" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6.0_16"/>
<java initial-heap-size="536870912" max-heap-size="1073741824" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6.0_20"/>
```

I read somewhere that this might be the problem as the JRE must be an exact match. Does this hold any validity? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I found a solution that seems to work. Instead of adding a specific Java version in the ruleset.xml file I did the following  <action permission="run" version="1.6+" />. This solved the problem. Everything works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok managed to figure this out.

basically java now checks their own https://java.com/applet/JavaRemovalTool/launch.jnlp when it gets launched by the uninstallapplet.js

Java now doesnt like the fact that oracle.com is listed in the jnlp file.

Thank goodness the jnlp is a text file and can be opened to see this.

So after adding oracle.com to the java console security Exception Site list, all is well !!

or try directly in notepad at:

C:\Users\ **USERNAME** \AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using the plus (+) symbol tells the applet/JNLP on the site to use any version installed that is above 1.6. Including 1.7 or 1.8, which is not the desired outcome. Even with JRE 7u55 and early adopter version 8u20_b10, I am unaware of a version of JRE/JDK that works as advertised for forcing a site to use the version of JRE specified in the ruleset.xml. 8u20_b10 is close, but still has issues in our testing. Still waiting...